# Beginner iPhone Controller Question

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a view that only has a button UIButton. First time clicking the button will draw a square above the button and the second time will replace the square with a circle.

I need some help on writing the controller code. Please guide me to the right path. Thanks

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried?

Answer (score 0):

design a shape class.  Add your shapes as UIImageViews.  with each button click, change the alpha on click.

```
@interface Shape: UIView {
  UIImageView *square;
  UIimageView *circle;
  BOOL isSquare;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImageView *square;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImageView *circle;
@property BOOL isSquare;

-(void)changeShape;
@end

@implementation Shape
@synthesize square;
@synthesize circle;
@synthesize isSquare;

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {

if ((self = [super initWithFrame:frame])) {

    self.frame = //frame size.


    //assume a square image exists.
    square = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: [UIImage imageNamed: @"square.png"]];
    square.alpha = 1.0;
    [self addSubview: square];

    //assume a circle image exists.
    circle = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: [UIImage imageNamed: @"circle.png"]];
    circle.alpha = 0.0;
    [self addSubview: circle];

    isSquare = YES;

    }
    return self;
}

-(void)changeShape {

if (isSquare == YES) { 
    square.alpha = 0.0;
    cirle.alpha = 1.0;
    isSquare = NO;
 }

if (isSquare == NO) {
    circle.alpha = 0.0;
    square.alpha = 1.0;
    isSquare = YES;
}


}

//rls memory as necessary.
@end
```

////////////////////////////////in your view controller class.

instantiate your class and add it as a subview.

```
@class Shape;

@interface ShapeViewController : UIViewController {
    Shape *shape;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) Shape *shape;


-(IBAction)clickedButton:(id)sender;

@end
```

////////

```
#import "Shape.h"
@implementation ShapeViewController;

 //add your shape as a subview in viewDidLoad:

-(IBAction)clickedButton:(id)sender {
  [shape changeShape];
}
@end
```

That should give you a good basic implementation idea.  Essentially, you design a class and then change its shape with each click.  It should alternate from square/circle/square/circle.  Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried to run the code and got this error message "Incompatible type for argument 1 of 'setFrame' for this line: square = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: [UIImage imageNamed: @"square.png"]];

Comment: did you set a frame?  self.frame takes a CGRect struct.

Comment: could you briefly describe how to do that? thanks. also what is the difference between viewDidLoad and initWithFrame?